# Total order relations on $\mathbb{Z}_{2^n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, intuition

I'm a programmer and not a professional mathematician so I need some abstract-algebra help regarding the following question:

*Introduction:*

When performing integer comparison x86 `CPU`s have some instructions that compares only signed [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) integers. So in order to perform unsigned comparison we usually use the following proposition:

$a \leq_{signed} b \iff a + 2^{n-1} \leq_{unsigned} b + 2^{n-1}$

for $n$-bit integers (i.e `xor 0x800...000`). This is not really obvious for me so I'm looking for a formal proof of that "ought to be obvious" fact.

*My thoughts:*

Consider $\mathbb{Z}_{2^n}$ group with `+` operation and for any $m \in \mathbb{Z}_{2^n}$ define the following relations $\forall a \neq m:  a \leq_m a + 1$. So the signed and unsigned comparison can be defined as $\leq_{2^{n-1} -1}$ and $\leq_{2^n-1}$.

The first thing I'm considering to prove is that for each $m\in\mathbb{Z}_{2^n}$ there is only one total order relation $\leq_m$. This can be easily proven by assuming two different total order relations with $\forall a \neq m:  a \leq_m a + 1$ which are equal then.

Now I'm considering to prove that for any $m, k \in\mathbb{Z}_{2^n}$ we have $a \leq_m b \iff a + (m - k)\leq_k b + (m - k)$.

The question is if the latter statement is even true? If so, can you give a hint how to prove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood, (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#Converting_from_two%27s_complement_representation)) a signed $n$-bit integer $a$ (that is a integer $a$ such that  $-2^{n-1}\le a\le 2^{n-1}-1$) is presented in a memory in the unsigned form of its $n$-complement $a^*$, which is a binary representation of a unique integer $0\le a’\le 2^n-1$ such that $a=a’\pmod 2^n$. See also a bit below

> In two's complement notation, a *non-negative* number is represented by its ordinary binary representation; in this case, the most significant bit is $0$... negative numbers are represented by the two's complement of the absolute value.

Now let $-2^{n-1}\le a,b\le 2^{n-1}-1$.  Then $a\le b$ iff $a+2^{n-1}\le b+2^{n-1}$ and $0\le a+2^{n-1},b^{n-1}\le 2^n-1$. But not necessarily $a’\le b’$. For instance, if $n=2$, $a=-1$, and $b=1$ then $a<b$, whereas $a’=3>b’=1$. But when $a$ and $b$ have the same sign then $a’\le b’$ iff $a\le b$, see also, “[Why it works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#Why_it_works)”.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the following reasoning can be considered strongly mathematically correct, but anyway I will provide the way I currently see it:

> Now I'm considering to prove that for any $m,k\in\mathbb{Z}_{2^n}$ we have
>
> $a\leq_m b \iff a + (m - k) \leq_k b + (m - k)$

For any $m\in\mathbb{Z}_{2^n}$:

$ a\leq_m b \iff \exists i \in \{0, 1, ..., m - a\}: b = a + i \iff \exists i \in \{0, 1, ..., m - a\}: 1 + b = 1 + a + i \iff \exists i \in \{0, 1, ..., (m + 1)- (a + 1)\}: 1 + b = 1 + a + i\iff a + 1 \leq_{m + 1} b + 1$

Now by induction we can see that $a \leq_m b \iff a + (k - m)\leq_{m + (k - m)} b + (k - m) \iff a + k - m \leq_{k} b + k - m$.

So as noted in the question the unsigned comparison is $\leq_{2^n -1}$ and signed comparison is $\leq_{2^{n-1} - 1}$ we have that:

$a \leq_{signed} b \iff a + 2^{n-1} \leq_{unsigned} b + 2^{n-1}$